# Dispatching and Ducktyping error, Unresolved Reference after indentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am at my wits end on why I cannot stop getting errors with my code. Here is part of my code that I am stuck with. The objective is to have the function repeat until the desired is inputted from the user. After creating the function (myproject) and applying indentation of the list I cannot get it to run anymore.   Any help would be appreciated.

```
def myproject() :

Joblist = []
employee1_dict = {'Title':'Blahblah', 'Vacation Days': 3}
Joblist.append(employee1_dict)

employee2_dict = {'Title':'blahblah2','Vacation Days': 5}
Joblist.append(employee2_dict)

print ('Welcome To Your Employee Vacation Request Portal!')


def bagbag(prompt):
    if  prompt == employee1_dict ['Title']:
        print ("Greetings blahblah!\nYou Have a Total of 3 days To Use")
    else :
        cashcash(prompt)
def cashcash(prompt):
    if  prompt == employee2_dict ['Title']:
        print ("Greetings blahblah2!\nYou have a Total Of 5 Days To Use")
    else :
        print ("I Do Not Recognize That Response(Please Remember I Am Case-Sensitive!) ")
        myproject()

prompt = raw_input('Please Enter Your Title\n')
bagbag(prompt)
```

Comment: whats the error that you're getting? a stack trace would be helpful Rickey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. You are creating a dict for each employee title and put it into a big list, but you never use the list but rather access each dict manually. May I suggest using only one dict with the title as key and the vacation days as value?

Secondly, you hard code the possible vacation values into your code. If you would have another group in the future, you would have to add another dict and another checking function. With the single dict approach, you would only have to add one key-value-pair.

Lastly you want to repeat the input process until something valid has been typed in. That calls for a loop, you are doing recursion by calling the whole function again.

Since you are using the `print()`-function, I am assuming you are using python3.x - there is no `raw_input()` there, just `input()`.

As an example, you could do this (I used your original spelling for the prompts):

```
vacationDict = {'Blahblah':3,
                'blahblah2':5}

print('Welcome To Your Employee Vacation Request Portal!')

while True:
    prompt = input('Please Enter Your Title\n> ')
    if prompt in vacationDict:
        print("Greetings {}!\nYou Have a Total of {} days To Use".format(prompt, vacationDict[prompt]))
        break
    else:
        print("I Do Not Recognize That Response (Please Remember I Am Case-Sensitive!)")
```

Comment: I am using 2.7 right now.. and the reason for the big list was to access the dict's separately, and eventually the code would print the estimated gross pay for the days they take off but i could not make it past this initial hurdle.

Comment: For python 2.7 simply change `input` back to `raw_input` and adjust the `print` statements. I hope this was helpful so you could continue with your project.